# SQL Count Compare occurrences of one fields value in another

Tags: sql, postgresql, count

Im having issues with my query here. I have the table cites with the two fields bookno and citedbookno. I am trying to find the bookno of each book that cites
another book, and also is cited by at least 2 books. The null part is fine but im wondering what is wrong with the count function

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.bookno
FROM cites c
WHERE c.citedbookno IS NOT NULL
AND COUNT(SELECT x.citedbookno
          FROM cites x
          WHERE x.citedbookno = c.bookno) > 1;
```

Comment: Do the COUNT inside the subquery.

Comment: `AND (SELECT COUNT(x.citedbookno)`

Answer (score 0):

try following

```
     SELECT DISTINCT c.bookno
FROM cites c
WHERE c.citedbookno IS NOT NULL
AND (SELECT COUNT(x.citedbookno)
          FROM cites x
          WHERE x.citedbookno = c.bookno) > 1;
```